# no borrar base de datos SQLITE-Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Se me ocurrió crear una aplicación que permita recuperar datos de usuario al reinstalarla en el dispositivo. Todas las apps que he creado previamente mantiene la información en una base de datos y la información se pierde cuando desinstalo la aplicación. 
Existe alguna forma segura de mantener la información de una base de datos aun cuando la app se desistale?. 
Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo logico seria mantener una base de datos remota sincronizada con la base de datos local pero desconzco los alcances de tu aplicacion.

Comment: no encuentro lógico querer mantener respaldos en tu celular de una aplicación ya desintalada, lo mejor que puedes hacer es que al reinstalar una apk, validez el numero de la versión de la base de datos y de acuerdo a eso crees, limpies o la sigas usando

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre es poder hacer un backup en un lugar especifico, y tener presente en que momento programas tu copia de respaldo y al desinstalar e instalarlo verificar si existe el archivo para sobreescribirlo. Aqui hay un link de la seccion de backup. Espero que te sirva
http://www.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2013/06/copia-de-seguridad-de-sqlite-a-la-unidad-sdcard-en-android/

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar una copia de la base de datos en tu almacenamiento externo pero  en otra ruta diferente al que usa tu aplicación.

Ejemplo, suponiendo tu aplicación tiene un package name  llamado `"com.kevtho.app"` , puedes usar un paquete diferente para definir otra ruta por ejemplo:

si generas esta ruta:

```
String mypath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
"/Android/data/com.kevtho.basededatos/misbd";
```

al eliminar tu aplicación esta ruta que contendría la base de datos, permanecería intacta.

Dependiendo de la cantidad de datos, si son considerables o es información más sensible podrías considerar consumir un Web Service.

---

Lo que menciona este articulo: 
[Copia de seguridad de sqlite a la unidad sdcard en Android](http://www.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2013/06/copia-de-seguridad-de-sqlite-a-la-unidad-sdcard-en-android/), **funciona pero es importante que cambies el nombre del paquete por uno diferente al de tu aplicación** para que cuando se borre no se eliminen los datos.

```
public void backupdDatabase(){
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        String packageName  = "com.yourapp.package";
        String sourceDBName = "mydb.db";
        String targetDBName = "mydb";
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            Date now = new Date();
        String currentDBPath = "data/" + packageName + "/databases/" + sourceDBName;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm"); 
        String backupDBPath = targetDBName + dateFormat.format(now) + ".db";

        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        Log.i("backup","backupDB=" + backupDB.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.i("backup","sourceDB=" + currentDB.getAbsolutePath());

        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
        src.close();
        dst.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Backup", e.toString());
    }
}
```